# PHP method chaining benefits?

Tags: php, oop, method-chaining

Still on the PHP-OOP training wheels, this question may belong on [failblog.org](http://failblog.org/). =)

What are the benefits of method chaining in PHP?

I'm not sure if this is important, but I'll be calling my method statically. e.g.

```
$foo = Bar::get('sysop')->set('admin')->render();
```

From what I've read, any method which returns `$this` is allowed to be chained. I just learned this is new in PHP5. Seems to me there may be speed benefits if I don't have to instantiate a whole new object (calling it statically) and just select the few methods I need from the class?

Do I have that right?

Comment: It's called a "fluent interface", it's not new, it just apparently did not work prior to PHP5

http://devzone.zend.com/article/1362

Comment: This works now? Lovely! Didn't know that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no significant performance benefits to using either approach, especially on a production server with byte code cache.

Method chaining is just a shorter way of writing things. Compare with the longer version:

```
$foo = Bar::get('sysop');
$foo -> set('admin');
$foo -> render();
```

It does have some quirks, though: a typical IDE (such as Eclipse) can auto-complete your code in the longer version (as long as the type of `$foo` is known) but needs you to document the return type of all methods to work in the short version.

Comment: i did some benchmarks on it, returning $this instead of returning void seems to use about 17 nanoseconds slower on my i7-6700 in power-saving mode on battery on a laptop with PHP 7.1.16, benchmark code can be found here: https://github.com/Znote/POTCP/commit/10cd616ffb8257216a8ede8fbe5ce625899536b9

Answer (score 1):

It still instantiates an object; it's just never assigned to a variable. Basically, you're just calling the methods of an anonymous object.

I think any cycle-savings would be negligible, but I think the unassigned objects would be freed immediately after this line of code, so you may have some memory savings (you could accomplish the same by setting assigned objects to `null` when you were done with them).

The main reason people use method chaining is for convenience; you're doing a lot in one line of code. Personally, I think it's messy and unmaintainable.

Answer (score 0):

> if I don't have to instantiate a whole
>   new object (calling it statically) and
>   just select the few methods I need
>   from the class?

Wrong! To return `$this`, the class has to be instantiated.