# use $this like return in php classes methods

Tags: php, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP method chaining benefits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976575/php-method-chaining-benefits)
>   [PHP OOP: Method Chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990952/php-oop-method-chaining)

could someone tell me why to use 
return $this;
in a php class method,
i have seen that in some method classes like:

```
public function registerPrefix($prefix, $path)
{

    if(isset($this->prefixes[$prefix])) {
        $path = array_merge($this->prefixes[$prefix], (array) $path);
    }
    $this->prefixes[$prefix] = (array) $path;
    return $this;
}



public function register()
{
    spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loadClass'));
    return $this;
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 4):

So that method calls are chainable, e.g.

```
$myobj->registerPrefix("something", "something")->register();
```

If you return the object itself from a method call, then you can call methods on the return value of a method.

Comment: +1 Correct. See [Fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) and [Method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

Answer (score 1):

This allows to call multiple methods of the same objects like this:

```
$object->registerPrefix(...)->register();
```

This allows to create fluent/chainable interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

It allows for the chaining of method calls, such as:

```
$ob->step1()->step2()->step3();
```

as apposed to:

```
$ob->step1();
$ob->step2();
$ob->step3();
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally you use `return` to make the function return a value.

Specifically you use `return $this` to return the object.

This sometimes is used for method chaining:

```
$that = new ThisClass();

$that->does()->what()->ever();
```

Was modern some-time ago. Can be helpful, but has limits:

```
$that->does()->what()->ever()->and()->how()->to()->handle()->errors()->and()->very_long()->chains()->question_mark()->exclamation_mark();
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach allows *method chaining*, for example:

```
$object->method1()->method2()->method3();
```

as opposed to:

```
$object->method1();
$object->method2();
$object->method3();
```

Answer (score 1):

`$this` is usually returned to allow method-chaining...Here's a good link:

http://www.talkphp.com/advanced-php-programming/1163-php5-method-chaining.html

Answer (score 1):

The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called statically from the context of a secondary object).  You can return whatever you want from a PHP function.  It does *not* have to be $this.

Comment: Interesting with the static calls. You have a link about that?

Comment: @hakre: http://no.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Comment: Hmm, then I don't understand what you're referring to. In static function calls, there is no `$this` at all. Please elaborate.